# Using net localgroup to add a domain security group to the Power Users local group

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, active-directory

For some reason, I am getting a syntax error when I try the following:

```
net localgroup "power users" "mydomain\Cisco Call Center Agents" /add
```

Howerver, the following works perfectly:

```
net localgroup "power users" "mydomain\Desktop Admins" /add
```

Both "Cisco Call Center Agents" and "Desktop Admins" are global security groups in the domain mydomain. Any thoughts on what is causing this?

OS is Win7 x64.

Thx,

Chck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the net.exe limitations listed here?

> #### [NET.EXE /ADD command does not support names longer than 20 characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324639)
>
> The NET.EXE command does not support names longer than 20 characters for reasons of backward compatibility with LAN Manager 2.0.
>
> For additional information about this LAN Manager 2.0 limitation, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
> [131417](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131417) – Windows NT global groups are limited to 20 character names